# displaying standard WP get_content with 'Advanced Custom Fields'

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following loop that utilises Advanced custom fields (ACF) - Everything displays except the content. I have tried various solutions with no success.

```
<?php
          $posts = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'sectors',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'
          ));
          global $post;
          if($posts) {
            ?>

            <?php
            foreach($posts as $post) {
              ?>
              <div class="content full sector">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    </div>
              <?php
            }
            ?>

             <?php
          }
          wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `get_posts()` to return post data, some post-related data is not available by default. One of these items is `the_content()`. This is resolved by calling an internal function `setup_postdata()`, with the `$post` array as its argument.

**Solution:** Add `setup_postdata( $post );` within your `foreach()`.

Read more [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data).

Comment: Great, please select this answer as correct to mark your question as resolved.